# Testing gRPC services using xUnit in c#

Tags: c#, grpc, xunit

I have a repository as a seperate project  **(MyRepo)** and using this repository I call various grpc services.

I haven't deployed the grpc servers yet so I run them on localhost:5000 for testing purposes.

**The error I'm getting is :**

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
> refused it. (localhost:5000)

which is obviously caused because the grpc server is not running.

if I open a new instance of the visual studio and start the grpc server and then run the unit test, everythings works perfectly.

I'm very new to the unit testing conecpt and I would like to learn how test this.

**My Code:**

```
public class StartupFixture
{
    public ServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; private set; }

    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

     public StartupFixture()
    {
        var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        configuration = configBuilder.Build();

        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.AddOptions();

        services.Configure<PlatformSettings>(configuration.GetSection("PlatformSettings"));
        
        services.AddScoped<ICmsService, CmsService>();

        services.AddScoped<IMyRepo, MyRepo>();

        ServiceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
}


public class UnitTestCmsPlatforms : IClassFixture<StartupFixture>
{
    private ServiceProvider _serviceProvider;


    public ImyRepo myRepo => _serviceProvider.GetService<IKoopRepo>();
    public UnitTestCmsPlatforms(StartupFixture fixture)
    {
        _serviceProvider = fixture.ServiceProvider;       
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task<List<Platforms>> Test1()
    {
       return  await myRepo.CmsService.GetAllPlatformsAsync();
    }
}
```

any help is much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: If you want to run tests that contain both client and server (that communicate with each other), I think your best bet is to actually look at the existing tests of grpc-dotnet itself. In lots of the test for the client (see https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/tree/master/test/Grpc.Net.Client.Tests), you actually need to have a running server - which I believe is a very similar situation to yours.

Answer (score 0):

My initial approach with Visual Studio isto  create a command line interface (CLI) project that can connect to the dev gRPC service.  **To run both, simply go to the Startup Project in your solution...select both the gRPC project and CLI project**.  I also created a delay...Console.ReadLine(), so the CLI does not talking to the service before it's ready.  This gets the job done, but it requires a lot commenting and organizing, so things don't go out of control.

With that said, I am seeking an alternative w/ xUnit...if it exists.